# Jquery Mobile need a drop down to choose US States

Tags: jquery-mobile

I need a drop down in my Jquery Mobile application where the user can choose US States.

What is the best control to use for this?

I was thinking of using the

```
   ListView
```

but wasn't sure if there was a better control for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the jquery-mobile drop-downs aka as [selects](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/forms/selects/)? (also look at the page for [custom selects](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/forms/selects/custom.html)).

In fact in the documentation page for the custom selects that I linked to ( the example given is for a drop-down with the US States.